Sqlalchemy replace a relationship with it's foreign key value
Consider the following schema
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ... # A lot of other attributes and relationships

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "childs"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id"), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship(Parent)
    ... # A lot of other attributes and relationships

(I am using Sqlalchemy 1.4)
Let's say I have a Parent object from a previous session
session.expire_on_commit=False
parent = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id == 1)

and I try to insert a new Child instance based on it:
new_child = Child(parent=parent)
session.add(new_child)
session.commit()

This would work, but it is not thread-safe as if I am trying to create a lot of Child instances in parallel regarding the same parent, I get an error similar to this.
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Parent at 0x7fdcf96bdc10>' is already attached to session '51' (this is '52')

(The error either comes from the Parent class or another class it is in relationship with).
I cannot just instanciate the Child with the parent_id key either, because a lot of the behavior of the application is based on the attributes of the parent and it's relationships.
Naively, I thought I could do something like
# Run the application, and when needing to insert the Child, with a new session do:
child.parent_id = child.parent.id
child.parent = None

Event though the representation looks ok <Child id=None, parent_id=1, ...>, when I run
session.add(child)
session.commit()

I get an error ```{'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '23502', 'M': 'null value in column "parent_id" of relation "childs" violates not-null constraint...'`
Indeed, somewhere during the commit my parent_id has been replace and my child now looks like this <Child id=None, parent_id=None, ...>.
I have tried the session.merge method described in this answer, but as my real world example handles a lot more relationships and attributes, it seems to try to create duplicate values.
What I am looking for in an answer:

Require minimal code change. If there is a simple method call that allows me to set the parent relationship to None while allowing parent_id to be kept during a session commit, this would be the perfect solution
Allows far more complex relationship patterns to play out (e.g have a GrandChild class that has a relationship to a child and that will be inserted at the same time as the child instance


It's not enough to expire the parent, you would need to expunge it from the previous session (unless you still require it in the previous session)

Thank you for the hint ! Do you mind elaborating a bit on that please ? From the documentation.
I have trouble understanding which session I should expunge, as the error comes from the sessions inserting the childs in parallel, but regard the parent instance

Based on your question, you would expunge the parent from the original session, then merge it into the session that is creating the child.  In fact you could keep a copy of the expunged parent and merge it when ever required, SQLAlchemy won't complain as long as it isn't the same instance I think.  But I don't understand enough about your situation to know if this won't cause other issues (such as concurrent updates on the parent row in the db)

Sadly this solution does not work: I still get the InvalidRequestError where the Parent instance tries to be attached to two sessions.
Creating a copy of the instances might work based on my answer, but my real-life case is far more complex and it would be a nightmare to do

I made a script to test the combinations of session type and parent status, and add-ing to the session worked in every case except when the parent wasn't expunged from the original session and the session was not scoped; in that case the child needed to be merged. If that solves your problem I'll make it an answer. If not, please [edit] the question to provide an [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

The only solution I have been able to come up with at the moment is to create a new Child instance without specifying the
new_child_to_insert = Child(parent_id=new_child.parent_id, ...) # Use a lot of other attributes
session.add(new_child_to_insert)

However, this solution is very cumbersome for my real usage where I have a lot of different
attributes and relationship to manage in the Child class
